# Find the limit of $n^\alpha$ / $(1+p)^n$ as n tends to infinity.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Find the limit of $\frac{n^\alpha}{(1+p)^n}$ as $n$ tends to infinity.   $p>0$ and $\alpha$ is real.

I have the solution to this problem but i dont understand the logic behind the steps.

Can someone please help.

EDIT:- Actually i wanted to solve  it using the fundamental methods of sequence and series. It begins by saying  (1+p)^n is greater than nCk p^k which is greater than n^k* p^k/(2^k*k!)

hence, 0 < $\frac{n^\alpha}{(1+p)^n}$ < (2^k*k!/p^k) n^(alpha-k).

EDIT2 (@Did): It appears that the question is actually to prove that $$(1+p)^n\geqslant{n\choose k} p^k \geqslant n^kp^k/(2^kk!).$$

Edit (3) :- Here's the question and its answer from Rudin's book:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Exponential crushes $n^{\alpha}$, so the limit is $0$.

Comment: Perhaps post the solution you have and give some more information about the specific steps that are giving you trouble?  Help us better help you.

Comment: @KajHansen I mentioned the method used in the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You proved that, for every positive integer $k$ and for every $n\geqslant k$ (*actually, for $n\geqslant2k$, see below*), $$0 <\frac{n^\alpha}{(1+p)^n} < \frac{2^k\,k!}{p^k}\frac1{n^{k-\alpha}}.$$ For $k\gt\max(1,\alpha)$, this implies that the limit is zero.

**Edit:** To prove the upper bound above, note that $$(1+p)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n{n\choose i}p^i\geqslant{n\choose k}p^k,$$ and that, for every $n\geqslant2k$, $${n\choose k}=\frac1{k!}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(n-i)\geqslant\frac1{k!}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\left(\frac{n}2\right)=\frac1{k!}\frac{n^k}{2^k}.$$ Thus, the book probably explains that their upper bound is valid for every $n\geqslant2k$.

Comment: can you please explain a bit more how exactly the proof proceded, i couldn't grasp the origin of 2nd equality

Comment: ?? "the origin of 2nd equality" is your question.

Comment: yes thats the actual problem for me

Comment: Done. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: even i thought the same thing, that n greater than or equal to 2k must be true but it wasn't mentioned anywhere, so i wanted to verify. Thank u mery much.

Comment: Next time, include what you thought in the question, and write the question that actually interests you...

Comment: @Did, A question please! what would this proof fail in if $p\le0$?

Answer (score 1):

(This is an answer to the first version of question).

For example (de l'Hospital's rule for $x\in\bf R$):
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^\alpha}{(1+p)^x}
=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\alpha x^{\alpha-1}}{(1+p)^x\ln(1+p)}.
$$
Using enough number of steps we obtain $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{\alpha-k}=0$, while the dominator tends to infinity.

Comment: Its true that it can be proved easily using L'Hospital but i wanted to use sequence and series in order to find the limit. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Manish And can we expect, that full version of your question will appear in a predictable time?

Comment: Prove that the limit is 0, thats it. The 1st step of the solution i have mentioned in the edit.